# Pandas DataFrame.to_csv raising FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Hi: I am trying to use the Pandas DataFrame.to_csv method to save a dataframe to a csv file: The to_csv is working fine for 15 files and its throwing error for one file. I am looping through all the sheets in an excel file and creating separate folders for each tab and placing the csv file in the respective tabs. The same piece of code is working in test but failing in prod.

```
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name, dtype = str, keep_default_na = False)
    csv_file_name = f"{os.path.splitext(excel_file)[0]} - {sheet_name}.csv"
    # Create a folder with the sheet's name if it doesn't exist
    sheet_folder_path = os.path.join(processed_directory, sheet_name)
    if not os.path.exists(sheet_folder_path):
        os.makedirs(sheet_folder_path)      
    csv_file_path = os.path.join(sheet_folder_path, csv_file_name)                        
    
    df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False,sep = '~')
```

20 excel files with 8 tabs and it should be converted to 20 csv files with 8 folders. Please help.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: Check your read/write permissions on the prod env.

Answer (score 0):

Use pathlib to make sure that you're writing the path in the write format of running system.

```
from pathlib import Path
sheet_folder_path = os.path.join(processed_directory, sheet_name)
mydir = Path(sheet_folder_path) 

if not os.path.exists(mydir):
      mydir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

csv_file_path = os.path.join(sheet_folder_path, csv_file_name)    
csv_file_path = Path(csv_file_path)          
df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False,sep = '~')
```